# How to design algorithm to allocate members of overlapping sets so that they are sorted according to specific criteria

Tags: algorithm, sorting, variable-assignment

I need to write an algorithm (pseudocode is fine) to accomplish the following problem.

We have a list of supermarket grocery stores, say 3,000. We have a footfall rank score for each store from 1 to 3,000. The stores are identified by index numbers.

We have multiple lists of stores (all of which are members of the master list of 3,000 above) for various marketing campaigns which we wish to run; each store may feature only one campaign. The task is to allocate marketing campaigns to stores such that:

- each campaign gets as many stores as possible from its demanded list.
- the campaigns get the best footfall rank possible and the best footfall stores are shared out between the campaigns as fairly as possible

There may be up to 10 marketing campaigns to allocate and there may be any number of overlaps between them.

I have already created one algorithm shown below. This works successfully to equalise footfall rank but because it goes through the store list in footfall order, it's possible that we run out of stores without satisfying all demand.

The current method is as follows:

1. Rank the master store list in footfall order
2. Rank the campaign list in priority order (this makes little difference but anyway)
3. Take campaign list (1) - does it have all the stores it needs? If yes, go to next campaign and repeat. If not, is this store a member of campaign list (1)? If so, allocate campaign 1 to this store, move to next store. If not, go to next campaign and return to beginning of step 3.
4. Repeat until all campaigns have been allocated or you have run out of stores.

This method delivers a perfect share of footfall to the different campaigns, but because the overlap between any given campaign list and the master store list is different for each campaign, it's possible for a campaign to run out of stores before it has got all the stores it wanted, even if there are enough - just not enough when you go through them in footfall order sharing them out equallt as this method does.

Code not relevant as I will translate the right flow into JS.

Expected result using current algorithm:

Imagine that campaigns 1 and 2 both want 100 stores. We plot a Venn diagram showing that there are enough stores to satisfy 100 stores for each of 1 and 2 considering all the overlaps.

Desired result:  each campaign is allocated 100 stores. Footfall rank is equalised as far as possible given the allocation.

Actual result: Campaign 1 gets 100 stores, campaign 2 gets 84 stores, footfall rank is identical.

Looking at the Excel output, it is possible to swap stores from 1 to 2 such that 2 gets 100 stores and 1 is able to top up from stores that can only carry campaign 1. Footfall rank diverges slightly.

Comment: how you calculate footfall rank of a set of stores?

Comment: You count the number of shoppers entering in a given time period. But for the purposes of this exercise, it doesn't matter. Just assume that in the master store list we have the footfall rank and it's accurate. :-)

Comment: I mean you ask for campaigns to get the best footfall rank possible but all I know are a single store rank, how you calculate the rank of a campaign? Just the sum of its stores? Also "each campaign gets as many stores as possible from its demanded list." needs a more formal definition. Do you want to maximize the lowest quantity of stores a campaign gets from its demanded? Or you want to maximize the average?

Comment: Each store has a rank score from 1 to 3000. The footfall score of a campaign is defined as the mean of all its stores' footfall scores. 

I want to maximise the number of stores a campaign gets from its demanded list (priority 1) while, as far as is possible, ensuring that all campaigns have an equal best footfall rank (priority 2)

Comment: You can model this as an optimization problem, but your goal of what you want to optimize is not clear(mathematically). If you model it as an optimization problem, you can use a solver and get the exact answer. If not, you are just looking for an heuristic

Comment: How about timing? You said that there may be up to 10 campaigns (you probably mean possible overlaps). Imagine, you get ordered 2 overlapping campaigns at the same time and calculate some store distribution for them, 2 days later is ordered another campaign which overlaps with 1 and 2. You got enough stores to fullfill 1.requirement, but best scores are depleded for 1 and 2.

Comment: What I want to optimise is the allocation of campaigns to stores such that all campaigns get the largest possible percentage of their demand, and that as a second priority, that the average footfall rank is as even as possible.

Comment: Timing is not a problem - assume that all campaigns have exactly the same timing. 

It's not the easiesit thing to explain in short paragraphs so apologies if I could have been / be being more precise, I am doing my best. 

I think i may have solved it actually, if I have i'll post up the answer. If nothing else I'd appreciate learning where I'm going wrong in describing it! 

Also first time on stack overflow so..

Comment: "all campaigns get the largest possible percentage of their demand" isn't precise enough for a solver, because it leaves a tradeoff in play: If there are 2 campaigns, is it better to give the first everything it wants if that means nothing for the second?  You need to state a formula that (once assignments have been made somehow) evaluates to *a single number*: that can then be fed to a solver.  Assuming you want a roughly "balanced" distribution, a common way to do that would be to maximise the *smallest* number of stores assigned to any campaign (perhaps subject to other conditions).

Comment: An example fully precise optimisation problem: "Among all possible assignments of stores to campaigns in which every campaign is assigned at least 10 of its desired stores, choose an assignment that minimises the difference between the maximum and minimum average campaign footfalls."  Or maybe "in which no campaign misses out on more than 10 of its desired stores" is better.  Then keep increasing (or decreasing) 10 and resolving until no feasible solution can be found -- the previous answer should be good.